# In jq, how to convert nested arrays from an array of objects into a single object

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON document that looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "id": "bbb",
    "lines": [
      "bla bla bla"
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "ccc",
    "lines": [
      "lorem ipsum",
      "sample text"
    ]
  }
  {
    "id": "ddd",
    "lines": [
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "eee",
    "lines": [
      "some text",
      "some more text",
      "foobar"
    ]
  }
]
```

I am attempting to use `jq` to modify this document into something that looks like this:

```
{
  "bbb_0": "bla bla bla",
  "ccc_0": "lorem ipsum",
  "ccc_1": "sample text",
  "ddd_0": "foo",
  "eee_0": "some text",
  "eee_1": "some more text",
  "eee_2": "foobar"
}
```

How would I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of achieving the desired output, using [`map`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)), [`with_entries()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) and [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add):

```
map(.id as $id | .lines | with_entries(.key |= "\($id)_\(.)")) | add
```

Produces

```json
{
  "bbb_0": "bla bla bla",
  "ccc_0": "lorem ipsum",
  "ccc_1": "sample text",
  "ddd_0": "foo",
  "eee_0": "some text",
  "eee_1": "some more text",
  "eee_2": "foobar"
}
```

Aa you can test in this [online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OARl5HEuv7)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `with_entries` to convert the array into an object with defined keys, and `reduce` to construct the overall object:

```sh
jq '
  reduce .[] as {$id, $lines} ({};
    . + ($lines | with_entries(.key |= "\($id)_\(.)"))
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "bbb_0": "bla bla bla",
  "ccc_0": "lorem ipsum",
  "ccc_1": "sample text",
  "ddd_0": "foo",
  "eee_0": "some text",
  "eee_1": "some more text",
  "eee_2": "foobar"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CtaJXJ5xVw)